# Modify the test file template

Tags: intellij-idea, testng, kotlin

When selecting "Create test" on a Kotlin class, I would like to include additional imports by default. For example, at the moment, only `import org.testng.annotations.Test` is included but I would also like `import org.testng.Assert.*`.

**How can I modify the test file template for Kotlin/TestNG in IntelliJ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely, the generated Kotlin test class is actually first generated as a Java class and then quickly converted to Kotlin.

Thus, you can modify the `TestNG Test Class` template in `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `File and Code templates` -> `Code`.